# Create angular5-csv with multiple sheets

Tags: angular, typescript, csv, angular5, export-to-csv

I use [angular5-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular5-csv) to create and download csv file from my data.

Is there a way to create multiple sheets?

for example I have 2 objects : data1 and data2, and I want that each object will be displayed in a separate sheet.

```
var data1 = [
  {
    name: "Test 1",
    age: 13,
    average: 8.2,
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 2',
    age: 11,
    average: 8.2,
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 4',
    age: 10,
    average: 8.2,
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
];

var data2 = [
  {
    name: "Test 1",
    age: 13,
    average: 8.2,
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 2',
    age: 11,
    average: 8.2,
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 4',
    age: 10,
    average: 8.2,
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
];
```